# Unable to Make Payment via Paypal

Tags: paypal, payment

I have Paypal India Business account.  I am using Express Checkout on my magento store and many customers are unable to make payment.

When they redirect to Paypal's billing page and pay via Paypal account they get

```
We can't complete your purchase at this time.  Please return to merchant.
```

There are clients from US, UK and Australia.  I talked to Paypal support and they said that there is no problem with my Paypal's account.

Please help me as I can't tell my customers to try out different things to make payments.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a quick peek in the PayPal configuration and also the PayPal account , what is the website URL and PayPal account email address?
please also share the PayPal URL when the merchant is redirected to PayPal

Comment: Website: http://www.lotuscardstudio.com, Paypal mail: sharddhacreations@gmail.com, Paypal url when customer redirects to Paypal: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-0DP894101H9344239&useraction=commit

Comment: Anything for me to look at?

Comment: May you confirm if the base currency is a supported PayPal currency and a complete billing/shipping  address is supplied to PayPal for payment?

Comment: Yes.  I have contacted Paypal tech support and they say that payer's paypal account was unverified causing them to fail.

Comment: Thanks Fahim for helping out.